# Face Recognition Script using OpenCV and face_recognition Library

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, argparse, face-recognition

I'm working on a face recognition project and I'm having trouble with the following code. It's a python program that performs face recognition on images and realtime image using OpenCV and the face_recognition library. I'm encountering some issues and would appreciate any help in resolving them. When in realtime the opencv works and opens the camera but when a face is recognised the program directly closes and it shouldn't happen, if anyone has any solution I would appreciate it.

```
import argparse
import pickle
from collections import Counter
from pathlib import Path

import cv2
import face_recognition
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

DEFAULT_ENCODINGS_PATH = Path("output/encodings.pkl")
BOUNDING_BOX_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)  # Blue color (BGR format)
TEXT_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)  # White color (BGR format)


# Create directories if they don't already exist
Path("training").mkdir(exist_ok=True)
Path("output").mkdir(exist_ok=True)
Path("validation").mkdir(exist_ok=True)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Recognize faces in an image")
parser.add_argument("--train", action="store_true", help="Train on input data")
parser.add_argument("--validate", action="store_true", help="Validate trained model")
parser.add_argument("--test", action="store_true", help="Test the model with an unknown image")
parser.add_argument("-m", action="store", default="hog", choices=["hog", "cnn"], help="Which model to use for training: hog (CPU), cnn (GPU)")
parser.add_argument("-f", action="store", help="Path to an image with an unknown face")
parser.add_argument("--realtime", action="store_true", help="Enable real-time face detection using the camera")
args = parser.parse_args()


def encode_known_faces(model: str = "hog", encodings_location: Path = DEFAULT_ENCODINGS_PATH) -> None:
    """
    Loads images in the training directory and builds a dictionary of their
    names and encodings.
    """
    names = []
    encodings = []

    for filepath in Path("training").glob("*/*"):
        name = filepath.parent.name
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(filepath)

        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model=model)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, face_locations)

        for encoding in face_encodings:
            names.append(name)
            encodings.append(encoding)

    name_encodings = {"names": names, "encodings": encodings}
    with encodings_location.open(mode="wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(name_encodings, f)


def recognize_faces(image_location: str, model: str = "hog", encodings_location: Path = DEFAULT_ENCODINGS_PATH) -> None:
    """
    Given an unknown image, get the locations and encodings of any faces and
    compares them against the known encodings to find potential matches.
    """
    with encodings_location.open(mode="rb") as f:
        loaded_encodings = pickle.load(f)

    input_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_location)

    input_face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(input_image, model=model)
    input_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(input_image, input_face_locations)

    pillow_image = Image.fromarray(input_image)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pillow_image)

    for bounding_box, unknown_encoding in zip(input_face_locations, input_face_encodings):
        name = _recognize_face(unknown_encoding, loaded_encodings)
        if not name:
            name = "Unknown"
        _display_face(draw, bounding_box, name)

    del draw
    pillow_image.show()


def _recognize_face(unknown_encoding, loaded_encodings):
    """
    Given an unknown encoding and all known encodings, find the known
    encoding with the most matches.
    """
    boolean_matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(loaded_encodings["encodings"], unknown_encoding)
    votes = Counter(name for match, name in zip(boolean_matches, loaded_encodings["names"]) if match)
    if votes:
        return votes.most_common(1)[0][0]


def _display_face(draw, bounding_box, name):
    """
    Draws bounding boxes around faces, a caption area, and text captions.
    """
    top, right, bottom, left = bounding_box
    draw.rectangle(((left, top), (right, bottom)), outline=BOUNDING_BOX_COLOR)
    text_left, text_top, text_right, text_bottom = draw.textbbox((left, bottom), name)
    draw.rectangle(((text_left, text_top), (text_right, text_bottom)), fill=BOUNDING_BOX_COLOR, outline=BOUNDING_BOX_COLOR)
    draw.text((text_left, text_top), name, fill=TEXT_COLOR)


def validate(model: str = "hog"):
    """
    Runs recognize_faces on a set of images with known faces to validate
    known encodings.
    """
    for filepath in Path("validation").rglob("*"):
        if filepath.is_file():
            recognize_faces(image_location=str(filepath.absolute()), model=model)


def detect_faces_realtime(model: str = "hog", encodings_location: Path = DEFAULT_ENCODINGS_PATH) -> None:
    """
    Performs real-time face detection using the camera feed.
    """
    with encodings_location.open(mode="rb") as f:
        loaded_encodings = pickle.load(f)

    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Open the camera

    while True:
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()  # Read a frame from the camera feed

        # Resize the frame to reduce processing time (optional)
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]  # Convert BGR frame to RGB

        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame, model=model)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
            name = _recognize_face(face_encoding, loaded_encodings)
            if not name:
                name = "Unknown"

            # Scale the face locations back to the original size
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), BOUNDING_BOX_COLOR, 2)
            cv2.putText(
                frame,
                name,
                (left + 6, bottom - 6),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                1.0,
                TEXT_COLOR,
                1,
            )

        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)  # Display the resulting frame

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break  # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed

    video_capture.release()  # Release the camera
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Close all OpenCV windows


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if args.train:
        encode_known_faces(model=args.m)
    if args.validate:
        validate(model=args.m)
    if args.test:
        recognize_faces(image_location=args.f, model=args.m)
    if args.realtime:
        detect_faces_realtime(model=args.m)
```

Explanation: This code performs face recognition on images and videos using OpenCV and the face_recognition library. It consists of several functions, including encode_known_faces, recognize_faces, validate, and detect_faces_realtime.

The encode_known_faces function loads images from the training directory, detects faces, and extracts their encodings. These encodings are then saved in a pickle file.

The recognize_faces function takes an unknown image, detects faces, and compares their encodings against the known encodings from the pickle file. It displays the recognized faces with bounding boxes and labels.

The validate function is used to validate the known encodings by running recognize_faces on a set of images with known faces from the validation directory.

The detect_faces_realtime function performs real-time face detection using the camera feed. It continuously captures frames, detects faces, and recognizes them using the known encodings.

The script utilizes the argparse module to handle command-line arguments for different functionalities, such as training, validation, testing, and real-time detection. The chosen model (hog or cnn) can also be specified as a command-line argument.

ERROR CODE :

python .\detector.py --realtime
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Cartu\Downloads\materials-face-recognition\source_code_final\detector.py", line 171, in 
detect_faces_realtime(model=args.m)
File "C:\Users\Cartu\Downloads\materials-face-recognition\source_code_final\detector.py", line 130, in detect_faces_realtime
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in face_encodings
return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in 
return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss
5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x0000019DD1502D70>, array([[[179, 179, 179],
[179, 179, 179],
[179, 179, 179],
...,
[126, 129, 128],
[126, 130, 129],
[123, 130, 128]],

```
   [[181, 181, 181],
    [181, 181, 181],
    [180, 180, 180],
    ...,
    [123, 129, 136],
    [122, 130, 130],
    [122, 131, 131]],

   [[180, 180, 180],
    [179, 179, 179],
    [180, 180, 180],
    ...,
    [122, 128, 130],
    [124, 132, 132],
    [121, 130, 128]],

   ...,

   [[175, 174, 165],
    [172, 173, 168],
    [173, 174, 171],
    ...,
    [ 71,  71,  71],
    [ 71,  71,  71],
    [ 72,  72,  71]],

   [[176, 172, 165],
    [175, 172, 167],
    [172, 173, 169],
    ...,
    [ 65,  67,  67],
    [ 68,  69,  69],
    [ 60,  64,  63]],

   [[176, 171, 169],
    [174, 171, 169],
    [173, 171, 171],
    ...,
    [ 66,  66,  66],
    [ 70,  70,  70],
    [ 62,  65,  64]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x0000019DD19F07F0>, 1
```

I tried changing the code multiple times, deleting thing to find the error, i've been searching but can't find any information. If someone has any alternative, ive seen something about deepface but I don't know if it easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
from deepface import DeepFace

DeepFace.stream(db_path = r"C:\database", time_threshold=1, frame_threshold=5)
```

that's the best I got for the moment, now I'm trying to send a notification when a face is recognised

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).